# Why does scrollTo work in my ClickListener but not in AfterViewInit?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, scrollto

I am wondering why the following works:

```js
scroll(){
    window.scrollTo(0, this.ypos); // works perfectly fine
}
```

And in my html.component:

```html
<button (click)="scroll()">Scroll</button>
```

but the following won't work:

```js
ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.ypos); // is perfectly defined
    window.scrollTo(0, this.ypos); // won't work
}
```

Do anyone know why it does not work? `window.scrollTo()` does also not work for `ngOnInit` but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using window object, use angular [Viewportscroller](https://angular.io/api/common/ViewportScroller#getScrollPosition) service to scrolls to a specified position.

**component.ts**

```
   import { ViewportScroller } from '@angular/common';

   constructor(private viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {}

   ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0,this.ypos]); 
   }
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. From where do I have to import the service? EDIT: Nvm, I found it. I will try it if it is working, I will mark your answer!

Comment: Check this example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bcxr6n

Comment: Hey, I checked it and tried it. It works in your project. In my project it does not work but why?  In the console ```ypos``` is 300 but the page is not scrolling down..

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: I will try, it could take a bit longer.

Comment: Okay if you give reproducible example it will be easy to help!

Comment: Or try this setTimeout(()=>{ this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0,this.ypos]);  })

Comment: Hey, it does work with setTimeout() and waiting 3 seconds before scrolling. I have a lot of data to be displayed, is the view not initialized even in the AfterViewInit method because of the big data? It also works with 50ms but not less.

Comment: So the issue might be due to large data!

Comment: Yes, it might be. Do you have any approach to deal with such a problem?

Comment: One suggestion. you can set scrollToPosition after gettign all the data from API.